can the code for HapticSurface from the OpenHaptcis unity plug-in update after mesh deformations?
I am working on a simulation in Unity where a 3D object is being deformed, and I need the haptic surface to update whenever there is a mesh deformation. My object is a rigged body, and when the bones move, the mesh deforms, but the haptic surface remains in its previous position. The object was rigged on blender
I tried modifying the code, but I only recently started working with C#, and my changes either result in errors or don’t produce any haptic response.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif


//! This MonoBehavior can be applied to any GameObject with a MeshCollider or MeshFilter.
//! It allows for the easy customization of the haptic properties of a "touchable" object.
public class HapticSurface : MonoBehaviour {


    public enum HLTOUCH_MODEL { HL_CONTACT, HL_CONSTRAINT };
    public HLTOUCH_MODEL hlTouchModel = HLTOUCH_MODEL.HL_CONTACT;  //!< HL_CONTACT is a normal object, HL_CONSTRAINT will force the stylus to stick to the surface of the mesh.

    public enum HLFACING { HL_FRONT, HL_BACK, HL_FRONT_AND_BACK };
    public HLFACING hlTouchable = HLFACING.HL_FRONT; //!< Which surface will be touchable? Front, Back, or Both?

    private bool Flip_Normals = false;  //!< There isn't areally a reason to use this.  

    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] public float hlStiffness = 0.7f;    //!< Higher values are less 'rubbery'.
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] public float hlDamping = 0.1f;      //!< Higher values are less 'bouncy'.
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] public float hlStaticFriction = 0.2f;   //!< Higher values have more 'sticky' surface friction.
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] public float hlDynamicFriction = 0.3f;  //!< Higher values have more 'sliding' surface friction.
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] public float hlPopThrough = 0.0f;   //!< If non-zero : How much force is required to "pop" through to the inside of the mesh.

    public float snapDistance = 1.0f; //!< When in HL_CONTRAINT mode, the maximum distance the stylus will "snap" to the surface.

    private bool oldFlipNormals = false;
    private float oldStiffness = -1;
    private float oldDamping = -1;
    private float oldStaticFriction = -1;
    private float oldDynamicFriction = -1;
    private float oldSnapDistance = -1;
    private float oldPopThrough = -1;
    private HLTOUCH_MODEL oldTouchModel = HLTOUCH_MODEL.HL_CONTACT;
    private HLFACING oldFacing = HLFACING.HL_FRONT;



    //! Used automatically for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (GetComponent<MeshCollider>() == null && GetComponent<MeshFilter>() == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("HapticSurface has been assigned to object without mesh.");
        }

        if( gameObject.tag == "Untagged" )
            gameObject.tag = "Touchable";
        
    }
    
    //! Update is called once per frame and updates OpenHaptics with the current suface materials. 
    void Update () 
    {
        bool needUpdate = false;

        if (hlStiffness != oldStiffness) needUpdate = true;
        if (hlDamping != oldDamping) needUpdate = true;
        if (hlStaticFriction != oldStaticFriction) needUpdate = true;
        if (hlDynamicFriction != oldDynamicFriction) needUpdate = true;
        if (hlPopThrough != oldPopThrough) needUpdate = true;
        if (snapDistance != oldSnapDistance) needUpdate = true;
        if (hlTouchModel != oldTouchModel) needUpdate = true;
        if (Flip_Normals != oldFlipNormals) needUpdate = true;
        if (hlTouchable != oldFacing) needUpdate = true;

        if (needUpdate)
        {
            HapticPlugin.shape_settings(gameObject.GetInstanceID(), hlStiffness, hlDamping, hlStaticFriction, hlDynamicFriction, hlPopThrough);

            int M = 0;
            if (hlTouchModel == HLTOUCH_MODEL.HL_CONSTRAINT)
                M = 1;
            
            HapticPlugin.shape_constraintSettings(gameObject.GetInstanceID(), M, snapDistance);
            HapticPlugin.shape_flipNormals(gameObject.GetInstanceID(), Flip_Normals);

            int T = 1;
            if (hlTouchable == HLFACING.HL_BACK) T = 2;
            if (hlTouchable == HLFACING.HL_FRONT_AND_BACK) T = 3;
            HapticPlugin.shape_facing(gameObject.GetInstanceID(), T);

            oldStiffness = hlStiffness;
            oldDamping = hlDamping;
            oldStaticFriction = hlStaticFriction;
            oldDynamicFriction = hlDynamicFriction;
            oldTouchModel = hlTouchModel;
            oldSnapDistance = snapDistance;
            oldPopThrough = hlPopThrough;
            oldFlipNormals = Flip_Normals;
            oldFacing = hlTouchable;

        }
        
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        HapticPlugin.shape_remove(gameObject.GetInstanceID());
    }



}       
    

#if UNITY_EDITOR


[CustomEditor(typeof(HapticSurface))]
public class HapticSurfaceEditor : Editor
{
    override public void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        HapticSurface HS = (HapticSurface)target;

        if (HS.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>() == null && HS.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>() == null)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("*********************************************************");
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("   Haptic Surface must be assigned to an object with a mesh.");
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("*********************************************************");

        } else
        {
            HS.hlTouchModel = (HapticSurface.HLTOUCH_MODEL)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("HL_Touch_Model", HS.hlTouchModel);
            HS.hlTouchable = (HapticSurface.HLFACING)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("HL_Facing", HS.hlTouchable);

            switch (HS.hlTouchModel)
            {
            case HapticSurface.HLTOUCH_MODEL.HL_CONTACT:
                HS.hlStiffness = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Stiffness", HS.hlStiffness, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                HS.hlDamping = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Damping", HS.hlDamping, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                HS.hlStaticFriction = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Static Friction", HS.hlStaticFriction, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                HS.hlDynamicFriction = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Dynamic Friction", HS.hlDynamicFriction, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                HS.hlPopThrough = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Pop-through", HS.hlPopThrough, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                break;
            case HapticSurface.HLTOUCH_MODEL.HL_CONSTRAINT:
                HS.snapDistance = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Snap Distance", HS.snapDistance);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
#endif

